# What are Exchange 2007/BPOS Default Calendar Sharing Permissions?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, exchange-2003, bpos

We currently run an inhouse SBS Exchange 2003 box and are in the process of moving to BPOS/Exchange 2007.  In our current environment if I open a calendar of someone else I can only see their Free/Busy information/availability.  In BPOS if I do the same thing I can see full details of each appointment/meeting and can even open the meeting and view the contents of it.

I am not sure if we have a rule or setting in Exchange 2003 that limits calendar visibility or if there was a change to how 2007 shows calendar appointments.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked with MSFT support on this question.  Turns out any users specified as service administrators have full permissions to all users and objects.  Regular users cannot see other's calendars and mailbox items.

Sort of weird but it does help out.

Brent